# IIS backup on Multiple servers from Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, iis

Can someone help me with backup of IIS on multiple servers from powershell script remotely. I can take backup of IIS from powershell command.

**backup-webconfiguration -name IIS_backup.**

Also i have a batch script which takes backup but that works only for one server . I have to login locally and run this as a batch job.

```
@echo off
cls

pushd "%WinDir%\System32\inetsrv"

echo.| date | find /i "current">datetime1.tmp
echo.| time | find /i "current">datetime2.tmp

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6" %%i in (datetime1.tmp) do (
  echo %%n>datetime1.tmp
)
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6" %%i in (datetime2.tmp) do (
  echo %%m>datetime2.tmp
)
for /f "delims=/ tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (datetime1.tmp) do (
  set TMPDATETIME=%%k%%i%%j
)
for /f "delims=:. tokens=1,2,3,4" %%i in (datetime2.tmp) do (
  set TMPDATETIME=D%TMPDATETIME%T%%i%%j%%k%%l
)

appcmd add backups %TMPDATETIME%

del datetime1.tmp
del datetime2.tmp

set TMPDATETIME=

popd
echo.
```

Currently i have worked on these two scripts . If possible please help me with taking backup of IIS remotely on multiple servers either through powershell or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Provided PSRemoting is enabled on your web servers you can simply run the following command to run the backup on multiple computers:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName "webserver1","webserver2","webserver3" -Scriptblock {Import-Module WebAdministration; backup-webconfiguration -name IIS_backup}
```

You can also separate your server list from the command as follows:

```
$Computers = "webserver1","webserver2","webserver3"
invoke-command -ComputerName $Computers -Scriptblock {Import-Module WebAdministration; backup-webconfiguration -name IIS_backup}
```

You can then populate the $Computers variable in a variety of ways. For instance, from a text file or from and AD query.

Comment: Thanks for help. Code works fine. Is it possible to place the backup of iis on different location . Having said that if i am taking backup of multiple servers at a time then backup is getting created at location C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\backup\. So i want to place all servers backup on different servers as well so that if any issue occurs with IIS we can use restore from there.

Comment: Perhaps you could copy the backup it creates using copy-item?